# Got undefined while creating a MongoDB connection. The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: database, mongodb, server, connection, dotenv

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

This is my .env code
`mongo_url = mongodb+srv://atharva:omkamble@cluster0.z4zpchw.mongodb.net/resell?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

This is my code for dbconfig.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect(process.env.mongo_url)

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.on('connected', ()=>{
    console.log('connection established successfully');
})

connection.on('error', (err)=>{
    console.log('connection failed with - ', err);
})

module.exports = connection;
```

This is my server.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const app= express();
require('dotenv').config();
const dbconfig = require('./config/dbconfig');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on ${port}`));
```

`require('dotenv').config();`

I tried this line in my server.js code but still getting error